# Infinite loop with a custom hook with UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a custom hook and I have problems with an infinite loop.

There is the piece of code that implements the custom hook on my page:

```js
const handleOnFinish = response => {
    const {data} = response

    setIsLoading(false)
    setTableData(data)
    setPage(page)
  }

  const handleOnInit = () => setIsLoading(true)

  useEffectUseCaseTokenValidation({
    onFinish: handleOnFinish,
    onInit: handleOnInit,
    params: {nameToFilter: nameFilter, page},
    useCase: 'get_clients_use_case'
  })
```

And this is my custom hook:

```js
import {useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import Context from '@s-ui/react-context'

const noop = () => {}

export function useEffectUseCaseTokenValidation({
  onFinish = noop,
  onInit = noop,
  params = {},
  useCase = ''
}) {
  const {domain} = useContext(Context)
  const config = domain.get('config')

  useEffect(() => {
    onInit()

    domain
      .get(useCase)
      .execute(params)
      .then(response => {
        const {error} = response

        if (error && error.message === 'INVALID_TOKEN') {
          window.location.replace(config.get('LOGIN_PAGE_URL'))
        }

        onFinish(response)
      })
  }, [params]) // eslint-disable-line
}
```

With this, the `useEffect` is released again and again, instead of taking params into account. I add a `console.log` for params and is always receiving the same.

I was using this `useCase` correctly without the custom hook, so that is not the problem.

I want to use this custom hook to avoid to copy and paste the redirection on all UseEffects for all project pages.

Thank you!

Comment: `params` is a new JavaScript Object on every render, so when it's passed as a dependency to your `useEffect` it will always trigger it to be called again. List each of the unchanging values instead: `[params.nameToFilter, params.page]`.

Comment: When you disable the lint you should be sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the object ref, that means that you are passing `{nameToFilter: nameFilter, page}` as params but each time the components renders a new object ref is creating so, react compare both with the `===`, so if you run this code in your console

```
var params1 = { name: 'mike', age: 29 };
var params2 = { name: 'mike', age: 29 };
console.log(params1 === params2); // it will console false
```

that's because object declaration are not the same event when its key/value pairs are the same.

So to avoid infinite loop into your hook, you should use `useMemo` to avoid that, so try this

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
const params = useMemo(() => ({ nameToFilter: nameFilter, page }), [nameFilter, page])

useEffectUseCaseTokenValidation({
  onFinish: handleOnFinish,
  onInit: handleOnInit,
  params: params,
  useCase: 'get_clients_use_case'
})
```

`useMemo` will avoid recreating object reft in each render phase of your component

Please read the [useMemo react official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Please read this [post](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) to know the differences between values VS references comparison

Comment: Best response ever! It works and I understand it. Thank you!

Comment: I glad to know that it helped you. @Aitor